# How to write an integration test for my custom ant task

Tags: testing, ant, integration-testing

I would like to write a test for an ANT task that I wrote. Here is a pseude code example of what I imagine the result will look like (it tests the task "property" which already exists in ant. In my case it will obviously be my custom task rather than "property"):

```java
// setup
AntEnvironemt env = AntEnvironment.create(
"<project name=\"test\">" +
"  <target name=\"test\">" +
"    <property name=\"foo\" value=\"bar\"/>" +
"  </target>" +
"</project>");

// execution
env.runTarget("test");

//evaluation
assertEquals(env.getProperty("foo"), "bar");
```

How can something like this be done?

Comment: Does just evaluating with equals wrapped witin `if` or `condition` task won't do the trick for you post running your 'test' target:   <if>
 <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2="bar"/>
 <then>
                <echo message="Related actions here"/>
</then>
</if>

Comment: @aavv: In this case I still need to execute the xml somehow. But the greater problem is that my task that I eventually want to test does more complicated stuff than just setting an attribute. I'd need to implement my own assertion tasks and code my tests in ant. Surely a possibility, but nothing I am eager to do.

Comment: are you looking for extending with `extends org.apache.tools.ant.Task` with something like: https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AntUnit](https://ant.apache.org/antlibs/antunit/). It allows for higher-level testing of Ant tasks:

```
  <target name="testNoNestedTextButValueAttribute">
    <property name="foo" value="bar">
    </property>
    <au:assertPropertyEquals name="foo" value="bar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="testNestedTextAndValueAttribute">
    <au:expectfailure>
      <property name="foo" value="bar">
        hello
      </property>
    </au:expectfailure>
  </target>
```

The above examples can be found in the [Ant 1.9.3 source distribution](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi) in the file `apache-ant-1.9.3/src/tests/antunit/taskdefs/property-test.xml`.